# Is there a way to pop form errors off the display stack and/or prevent their display?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a Drupal 7 form which I'm allowing the user to submit via AJAX. If the user does not fill out required fields, or enters invalid information, I can return that and alert the user via the `form_get_errors()` function. The problem is that these values are still on the "display stack" (not the correct term, I'm sure) - when the user refreshes the page, or navigates to another one, these previous errors are displayed.

Is there a way to set these errors not to display once I've grabbed them with `form_get_errors()`?

EDIT: The session variable 'messages' is set at `$_SESSION['messages']['error']`, which is where the display of the errors is driven from. I could wipe this out by doing something like `unset($_SESSION['messages']['error'])`, but I feel like this is very hacky. The `drupal_static_reset()` function also will not help, since it doesn't eliminate the values in the messages array.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the message was the last one set, a  simple hack is to just:

```
array_pop($_SESSION['messages']['error']);
```

Just be aware this only removes the message, your form will still be in error state.

Comment: This would totally work, but I'll hang out a bit to see if there's a suggestion that's more inline with the Drupal workflow. I just can't believe that I'm the first person to try to use Drupal in this way. I mean...submitting forms via AJAX is pretty common, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its pretty common.. :)

But I have used the same technique, that is to unset the $_SESSION array.

Some of the modules store the errors as $_SESSION['module_name]['messages']['error'], which is good so that you dont unset some else's message.

I have used AJAX for form submit many times, but still haven't run into a better or more Drupal way to do this.

Will be glad to find something better than unset or array_pop ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can grab all the themed error messages by [`theme('status_messages', array('error'))`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7) which in turn calls [`drupal_get_messages()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7) which unsets the messages that got displayed. Or if you want a structured array of messages you can call `drupal_get_messages('error')` straight away. I'm not 100% certain this works for form errors, but I hope this helps.

Edit: Sorry didn't notice this question was from December 2011 -.-

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
drupal_get_messages($type = NULL, $clear_queue = TRUE);
```